# How to switch between applications in current workspace only in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

In unity, I used to configure in ccsm. How do I do it in gnome-shell?

Comment: Someone asked the same question (?) later, didn't find this question here, but found a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/ubuntu-gnome-force-alt-tab-to-only-switch-on-current-workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press Alt+Tab, it, indeed, shows all the applications (on all workspaces), but separates the applications on different workspaces by vertical lines. So, while this is not exactly what you want, it still may help a little.

I would suggest you install Gnome-Shell extension Window List (it is written for Linux Mint 12 Lisa and now available for Ubuntu in the WebUpd8 Gnome3 PPA). This extension shows buttons on the panel (on the top panel if the bottom panel, another their extension, is not installed or disabled) for all applications open in the current workspace only (open and minimized). They have application icons and title.

These buttons work as expected: when you click an unfocused application button, it brings it on top, when you click a button for the currently focused application, it minimizes it. When you switch the workspace, it shows the buttons for the applications on the new workspace.

This way you will have "Alt-Tab" list of applications on the current workspace always visible and at your hands. The only problem is that there is no shortcut to switch between them, you have to use mouse.

This is, probably, the best I could suggest for you at the moment.

Comment: Now there are lot of Alt+Tab alternative extensions available at https://extensions.gnome.org/ . One can choose depending on their requirement. I am marking this answer as expected because thats the best possible solution at that point of time. But for current users, check that site

Answer (score 6):

As linked in @black_puppydog's comment, [this answer by @daniel451](https://askubuntu.com/a/464947/168094) solves the problem:

> 1. Install `dconf-editor` (already installed on current debian/ubuntu distributions):
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
>    ```
> 2. Open `dconf-editor` (from the Dash or a Terminal)
> 3. Navigate to: org -> gnome -> shell -> app-switcher
> 4. Set "current-workspace-only" to true

**Note:** I copied the answer here before this was closed as duplicate.